# Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http://, https:// or ftp://) in Magento 1.9.2 installing?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http://, https:// or ftp://) in Magento 1.9.2 installing?

While installing Magento, I am facing error for web validation in Magento 1.9.2

Answer (score 78):

Resolve this issue by the following methods (from good to worse):

1)  Inspect the url field and delete the class 'validate-url' to stop validation from the field and proceed the process.
have a good Luck guys.

OR

2) just mark the "Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step" checkbox.

OR

3) use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost like
    http://127.0.0.1/magento192/

Comment: And flag "Skip base url validation" for me.

Comment: @AlessandroPirovano is right, just check the box "Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step", it's better than setting an url with 127.0.0.1/etc....

Comment: @Hassan Ali Shahzad I've improved your answer adding another alternative, hope you don't mind...

Comment: I faced same problem while trying to install magento 1.9.3. Fixed following step 2 & 3.

Answer (score 51):

We need to **disable URL validation** here.

**Quick solution:**

1. Inspect "Base URL" input in firebug
2. Remove "validate-url" from the list of classes
3. Click "continue"

Comment: Thanks!  The same goes for Chrome - inspect the Base URL input box element, remove the class from the list of classes.

Answer (score 10):

While installing Magento in the local server, in the configuration section, you may be asked to enter the base url. But the installation wizard will not accept the local server url. It is because

**Magento won’t consider the local server url as a valid url.**

For this you need to remove the validation for the particular section.

Open \app\design\install\default\default\template\install\config.phtml

Find the textbox where the base url is entered. It will be around line no 85 with name ‘config[unsecure_base_url]‘
Remove ‘validate-url’ from its class and save the file.

OR

Use Ip of your localhost,

http://127.0.0.1/magento/

Answer (score 10):

There is also a "Skip URL validation" box down below, if you check it, you can ignore the validation. But for some strange reason you still have to write a "correct" address, as mentioned in other answers, meaning `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Open \app\design\install\default\default\template\install\config.phtml
```

Find the textbox where the base url is entered. It will be around line no 85 with name `config[unsecure_base_url]`

Remove `validate-url` from its class and save the file.

Now you can continue the installation

It will work      (Niraj)

Answer (score 3):

For this you need to remove the validation for the particular section.
Open app\design\install\default\default\template\install\config.phtml
Find the textbox where the base url is entered. It will be around line no 50 and 94 with name ‘config[unsecure_base_url]‘
Remove 'validate-url' from its class and save the file.
Working fine
Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http://, https:// or ftp://)

Answer (score 0):

use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost is working fine

Answer (score -2):

NO much need to do all this.. you just need to go to web access checkbox options and see the base url checkbox text saying this simply::: check this option if url can not verify automatically.

check it and go on...