# Required entering a valid URL when installing Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

When installing Magento 1.9.2, I couldn't go to the next step because a URL validation occurred that required entering a valid URL. Older versions of Magento didn't have this issue. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670285/please-enter-a-valid-url-protocol-is-required-http-https-or-ftp-in). But I want to know the reason for this. Is there any security issue here?
Can you explain this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http://, https:// or ftp://) in Magento 1.9.2 installing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670285/please-enter-a-valid-url-protocol-is-required-http-https-or-ftp-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer on Magento Community forum:

> Its because localhost isn't actually a valid domain.since it doesn't have a TLD. I personally use localhost.com as mine so that it passes the URL checks. http://192.168.0.1/ etc.. is actually a valid domain which is why that passes the checks.
>
> The is an option during install that says something along the lines of skip url verification that you could use if you're 100% sure you've got the right domain.