# Don't know why magento is not installing?

Tags: magento

I am facing problem when installing magento on my xampp server. There is some path url issue which I have been facing. please look at the screenshot

chrome-extension://mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg/fsCaptured.html

Comment: Please post the relevant error message or a description of the problem.

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/hx20sz.png

Comment: I've facing problem when installing magento on my xampp server.

Comment: The image that can easily be posted here on StackOverflow. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Ok. next time ill do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open \app\design\install\default\default\template\install\config.phtml
2. Find the textbox where the base url is entered. It will be around line no 85 with name ‘config[unsecure_base_url]‘
3. Remove ‘validate-url’ from its class and save the file.

```
<li>
    <label for="base_url"><?php echo $this->__('Base URL') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label><br />
    <input type="text" name="config[unsecure_base_url]" id="base_url" value="<?php echo $this->getFormData()->getUnsecureBaseUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Base URL')) ?>" class="required-entry validate-url input-text" />
</li>
```

Replace with

```
<li>
    <label for="base_url"><?php echo $this->__('Base URL') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label><br />
    <input type="text" name="config[unsecure_base_url]" id="base_url" value="<?php echo $this->getFormData()->getUnsecureBaseUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Base URL')) ?>" class="required-entry input-text" />
</li>
```

4.Refresh installation page and continue.

Answer (score 0):

Try check "Skip Base URL Validation Before the next step"

[image]

Take a look at [Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http://, https:// or ftp://) in Magento 1.9.2 installing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670285/please-enter-a-valid-url-protocol-is-required-http-https-or-ftp-in)